# Two functionality for left slide ios

Tags: ios, iphone, slider, master-detail

I am building an iphone application which is a aster details app. By default, the left slide for the table cell gives the delete option. But i want to add one more option to that (Edit). Just like the latest whatsapp does. Can anyone give pointers how to proceed with this and oblige.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to setup a custom swipe with custom buttons:

[Custom Table cell view](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell)